# Area size of polygons with same value (building id) in GRASS GIS

Tags: polygon, grass-gis, area

Is there a way to calculate the area size of multiple polygons having the same value (in this case building number) like group stats in QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this in GRASS uses a reclass of the vector layer, then when you update the database of this reclass vector with i.e. area, the total of the reclassed features will be calculated. See: [v.reclass man page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.reclass.html)

If you have a `buildings` polygon with a **integer or text** field `building_num`, then:

```
v.reclass input=buildings output=buildings_by_num column=building_num
v.db.addtable map=buildings_by_num column="ttl_area DOUBLE"
v.to.db buildings_by_num option=area unit=meters column=ttl_area
v.db.select buildings_by_num  # should show one total value for each building num
```